# Does this computer have a steering wheel?

Tags: identify-this-computer

I don't really know what the round object is, but it certainly resembles an old-time steering wheel.

This image was [used as an example at this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images). I don't know what its original source was, it is uncited.

[image]

I'm not even entirely certain this is even a computer. The gauges suggest it could perhaps be an industrial control system. On the other hand there is a keyboard "terminal" with some kind of printer output.

So, obviously I don't know much - but I am interested in what this computer is, and what that particular device is for.

Comment: The idea reminds me of [the Rice R1’s debugging crank](https://web.archive.org/web/20170902000907/http://www.cs.rice.edu/History/R1/)! (This photo is obviously not that.) The R1 is also famous for its RLH Condition Test.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the image is a hoax.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Questions should only be closed based on the content of the question, not what the answer is. The question is asking to identify something purported to be a computer, and it's not obvious that it's not one.

Comment: @RossRidge You're right. Sorry!

Comment: I'm very tempted to vote close, But then again, Identify-This is quite valid on RC.SE, even tough it's obvious pointless. We got stay objective no matter how much it hurts on the inside :))

Comment: This joke keeps coming back again and again. If Retro.SE needs to have a Snopes-style entry to handle it, so be it. But the image has all the verisimilitude of vintage sci-fi TV show computer... I mean, a wide-format teletype, analog gauges, **and** a CRT **and** a submarine trim wheel? Trying too hard.

Comment: Especially a *raster* CRT at a type where glass TTYs were not invented yet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Via [TinEye](https://tineye.com/), I found this image on a Snopes FACT CHECK page: [Claim:   Photograph shows RAND Corporation’s 1954 design for a home computer](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/does-not-compute/).

It's a hoax image, a composite of a submarine maneuvering room console used in a FARK.com image modification competition in 2004.

The original and real image:

[image: real image]

Comment: And FWIW, the "teletype" looks like it's actually a DEC LA36 from the mid-1970s.

Comment: @another-dave Exactly! I stared at that for a minute and thought "that sure looks like a DECwriter, when the only thing matching the rest of the equipment would be, at best, a TTY 33.